# How does Amazon Sqs configure the message SentTimestamp, when it is not specified in the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am wondering how does Amazon SQS handle the SentTimestamp while sending a message to a queue?

- If the SentTimestamp attribute is not specified in the request, does Amazon take their system timestamp when it receives the message in the sqs to be the SentTimestamp value?
- From my experiments, even if I specify the SentiTimestamp attribute in the request, I do see Amazon does not take the value as message SentTimestamp.
- If my local system clock is out of synch with NTP server, does it give any influence on the SentTimestamp attribute?

Can someone please help clarify these questions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The SentTimestamp attribute is set by SQS and is read-only, you cannot override the SentTimestamp attribute with some other value.

Note that the SQS documentation only mentions SentTimestamp in the ReceiveMessage section. SentTimestamp comes from the Attributes field, which is distinct from the MessageAttributes field. While you can specify MessageAttributes when sending a message, you cannot specify Attributes when sending. Therefore, the Attributes field must be populated by SQS.

If the sender's clock is wrong, it will have no effect on the SentTimestamp value. 
However, if the receiver's clock is wrong you may get some incorrect results when trying to process the SentTimestamp value.

Source: [SQS API Documentation](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/SQS/latest/sqs-api.pdf).